# How is $A_3$ normal in $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups

I notice that conjugation works, but:

$(12)(123) = (123)(12) \rightarrow (1)(23)=(13)(2)$

Is clearly wrong. Doesn't normality imply that $hg=gh$ for $H$ being normal in G?
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Another way of looking at Normal subgroups is the following: if H is a normal subgroup, then Hx=xH, ie. the left cosets are equal to the right cosets. This however does not imply that H is a Centralizer.

Comment: Normality is akin to commutativity but at the level of subgroups. It is not the same however.

Comment: H being normal does not imply that hc=ch.

Comment: You can also argue that because $[S_3:A_3]=2$, $A_3$ is a subgroup of index $2$, so it is normal in $S_3$.

Comment: @ilovebulbasaur Why is it that a subgroup of index 2 has to be normal?
Update:
Ah, never mind, it's because it has only two cosets H and Hx, so Hx=xH.
Anyway, that's an interesting argument.

Answer (score 5):

A normal subgroup H of G, is a subgroup such that for any $h$ from $H$, $xhx^{-1} \in H$ i.e. all the conjugates ($xhx^{-1}$) of $H$ are in $H$. Another way to look at it is the following: the left and right cosets of $H$ are the same, meaning $Hx=xH$. Basically saying that multiplying $H$ by an element is commutative. (Remember $Hx$ is the set all of elements of $H$ multiplied by $x$).

However this does not imply that the elements of $H$ commute with themselves or with other elements of $G$. There is another subgroup which is called the centralizer, by definition it's elements are those elements of $G$ which commute with all of the elements of $G$.

Comment: Why the downvote? I am trying to explain things in detail and give more scope.

Comment: Was an honest misclick, my bad.

Comment: Never mind then.